# What am I doing wrong in align-items code?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align the img and text vertically but align-items is not working. I am using a bootstrap template. When I inspect the section it says "display: block;". Can that be the reason? You can see my code below:

html;

```
<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="./assets/img/about-us-img.avif" class="img-fluid" alt="about">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p>
          About text...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

css;

```
.about h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

#about .container {
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hi**,
[`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) Css Property. Works only with `display: grid` and `display: flex`

Otherwise it's not working. You can add `display: flex` property with `!important` declaration. But It can change the `col-lg-6` desgin

Or you can use `position: absolute` to align items vertically. But it isn't best practice

**With Display flex**

```
.about h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

#about .container {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**With Position absolute**

```
.about h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

#about .container {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
#about .container * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
#about .container {
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the custom class to the container and then add some extra styling to achieve this.

```css
.about h3 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.about-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}

#about .container {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container about-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="./assets/img/about-us-img.avif" class="img-fluid" alt="about">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>About Us</h3>
        <p>
          About text...
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```